Duality when trying to send a message via FCM tokens in Flutter app
I want to create a firebase cloud function that detects changes in a certain collection in firestorm, look for field matches in documents in a different collection, and then get the fcmTokens from those filtered documents.
This process works as expected, and the tokens are fetched properly, the actual problem arises when I try to send messages using them.
With the tokens, when I start a new message campaign in firebase console, they are being received by my main.dart, but the notifications sent by the functions code aren't.
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sreyas_one_hub/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:sreyas_one_hub/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:sreyas_one_hub/services/notification_service.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  const FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions();

  FilePicker.platform = FilePicker.platform;

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: firebaseOptions);

  final NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.init();

  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );


  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    if (notification != null) {
      notificationService.showNotification(
        title: notification.title!,
        body: notification.body!,
      );
    }
  });


  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  if (notification != null) {
    print("Notification title: ${notification.title ?? 'No title'}");
    print("Notification body: ${notification.body ?? 'No body'}");
  } else {
    print("Notification is null");
  }

  final NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.init();

  if (notification != null && notification.title != null && notification.body != null) {
    notificationService.showNotification(
      title: notification.title!,
      body: notification.body!,
    );
  }
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Sreyas OneHub',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? const LoginScreen() : HomeScreen(
        uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
      ),
    );
  }
}


and the index.js:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

async function sendNotifications(tokens, title, body) {
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: body,
    },
  };

  try {
    console.log("Sending notification: ", payload, " to ", tokens);
    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    console.log("Notification sent successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
  }
}

exports.onMarksChange = functions.firestore
  .document("marks/{markId}")
  .onWrite(async (change) => {
    const newValue = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;

    if (newValue) {
      const studentId = newValue.studentId;
      const studentDoc = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("students")
        .where("uid", "==", studentId)
        .get();

      if (!studentDoc.empty) {
        const studentData = studentDoc.docs[0].data();
        const tokens = studentData.fcmToken || []; 

        if (tokens.length > 0) {
          await sendNotifications(
            tokens,
            "Marks Updated",
            "Your marks have been updated."
          );
        } else {
          console.log("No fcmTokens found for this student");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Student document does not exist");
      }
    }
  });

exports.onStudentChange = functions.firestore
  .document("students/{studentId}")
  .onWrite(async (change) => {
    const newValue = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;

    if (newValue) {
      const tokens = newValue.fcmToken || []; 

      if (tokens.length > 0) {
        await sendNotifications(
          tokens,
          "Student Data Updated",
          "Your student data has been updated."
        );
      } else {
        console.log("No fcmTokens found for this student");
      }
    }
  });

exports.onScheduleChange = functions.firestore
  .document("schedules/{scheduleId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    const newSchedule = snap.data();
    const department = newSchedule.department;

    const studentsSnapshot = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("students")
      .where("department", "==", department)
      .where("year_of_study", "==", newSchedule.year)
      .get();

    const tokens = [];

    studentsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const studentData = doc.data();
      if (studentData.fcmToken && Array.isArray(studentData.fcmToken)) {
        tokens.push(...studentData.fcmToken);
      }
    });

    if (tokens.length > 0) {
      await sendNotifications(
        tokens,
        "New Schedule Added",
        "A new schedule has been added for your department."
      );
    } else {
      console.log("No fcmTokens found for students in this department");
    }
  });

exports.onExamChange = functions.firestore
  .document("exams/{examId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    const newExam = snap.data();
    const department = newExam.department;

    const studentsSnapshot = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("students")
      .where("department", "==", department)
      .where("year_of_study", "==", newExam.year)
      .get();

    const tokens = [];

    studentsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const studentData = doc.data();
      if (studentData.fcmToken && Array.isArray(studentData.fcmToken)) {
        tokens.push(...studentData.fcmToken);
      }
    });

    if (tokens.length > 0) {
      await sendNotifications(
        tokens,
        "New Exam Added",
        "A new exam has been added for your department."
      );
    } else {
      console.log("No fcmTokens found for students in this department");
    }
  });


Tried the following:

Message campaign from firebase console [works]
Individual FCM tokens instead of a array

Works in Firebase console, not in Functions


bash curl requests [works]
Search on SO

There seem to be a lot of problems which look like mine, but they're either related to problems with permissions regarding their projects, code debugging, or using deprecated code.



Replication:
I have the entire project in a GitHub repo, which I would be glad to give you access, if your initial suggestions do not work.
--extras--
These questions seem similar, but aren't exactly what helped me:

How to send a fcm notification using javascript cloud functions in flutter?
FCM Remote Message data is empty when received in flutter
Sending Push Notification to Multiple Selected Devices with FCM
Flutter app only receiving FCM messages to specific token


In your index.js, I see you are using legacy FMC APIs which is deprecated from July 22, 2024. In order to use, you need to migrate your code into Http v1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

@ThangPhi   const payload = {
notification: {
title: title,
body: body,
},
tokens: tokens,
};
await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload)

does this look right?

For each token, try const message = { notification: { title: title, body: body, }, token: token, }; then await admin.messaging().send(message)

It works! apparently you can only pass one singular token to the payload, I added an iteration through the list and used the send() method

I will summarize the issue you faced.
First of all, your dart code looks fine. From you js code you send push notification to list of tokens.
Currently sendToDevice(tokens, payload); is deprecated so you should use send(payload) instead. For tokens, you can add into your payload in order to push notification. Rest resource
Before
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: body,
  },
};

await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);

After
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: body,
  },
  token: token
};

admin.messaging().send(payload)

Above is an example for send one push notification, you can add an iteration through the list for sending list token.
